# Branch IO - Show referral parameters in custom event

Tags: android, branch.io

In my app I am tracking app install referrals using Branch and I also have a custom event called `SIGN_UP` which gets sent after the sign up request completes.|

So after using a branch link (fb one in particular) to install and sign up in my app, even though I get normal campaign data in the `INSTALL` event, I do not seem to get any relevant data in my custom one:

[Screenshot of dashboard webhook events when filtered by AAID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o0vV.png) (see how columns `Campaign`, `Ad Partner 3P`, `Ad Partner`, `Channel`, `Feature` are empty in the first row.)

Any reason why this happens?

Code used:

- In my Application class:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // ...
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    // ...
}
```

- In my launcher Activity:

```kotlin
private val callback = Branch.BranchReferralInitListener { referringParams, error ->
    if (error == null) {
        Timber.i("BRANCH SDK success: %s", referringParams.toString())
    } else {
        Timber.e("BRANCH SDK error: %s", error.message)
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Branch.sessionBuilder(this).withCallback(callback).withData(this.intent?.data).init()
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    Branch.sessionBuilder(this).withCallback(callback).reInit()
}
```

- When sending a `SIGN_UP` event:

```kotlin
Branch.getInstance().setIdentity(memberId)

BranchEvent("SIGN_UP")
    .addCustomDataProperty("UDID", udid) 
    .logEvent(activity)
```

**Branch version: 5.0.1**

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook as Ad Network, Branch has the following [data limitations](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-ads-overview#section-data-limitations)

1. We cannot send device-level Facebook attribution data to third parties.
2. We cannot send events attributed to Facebook via Data Integrations. Please instead consider analyzing this data in-house (using Webhooks, the Daily Export API, or CSV Exports), or using the Branch Dashboard for all of your analytics and attribution needs.
3. This data is also not returned in the deeplink session initialization callback within the app. Also, you must have signed Facebook's "Advanced Mobile Measurement" agreement ("Data Use Terms for Advanced Mobile App Measurement") to view this data.